How do I add multiple levels of subfolders?
I found this code to move an email to a folder in my Inbox. It works for a folder in the root.
How do I add multiple levels of subfolders?
I can move email to the "Agresso" folder but not to the "Sent" subfolder within Agresso.
Option Explicit

Sub MoveOpenMessage()
 
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objItem As Outlook.MailItem
    
    Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    ' Set the destination folder
    ' move to subfolder of inbox
    Set objDestFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Agresso/Sent")
      
    ' use selected message
    Set objItem = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
 
    ' use opened message
    'Set objItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    
    ' to move
    objItem.Move objDestFolder
        
    Set objDestFolder = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing
End Sub

I checked examples online but none seem to add subfolders.
I want to move the email down along the tree of subfolders.

In Outlook, every folder (Outlook.MAPIFolder) has a collection of items (the Mails and Meetings) and a collection of (sub-)folders.
If you need a subfolder of a subfolder, you need first the root folder (in your case the Inbox), look into the Folders-property of that folder to get the /first level subfolder (Agresso) and from that subfolder the next deeper level (Sent) - and so on if needed.
Your code could look like this:
Dim inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder, destFolder as Outlook.MAPIFolder
Set inbox = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set destFolder = inbox.Folders("Agresso")
Set destFolder = destFolder.Folders("Sent")

I usually don't cascade multiple steps in one command, splitting it helps debugging. But if you insist, you can also write
Dim destFolder as Outlook.MAPIFolder
Set destFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Agresso").Folders("Sent")


That is brilliant FunThomas.  Thank you for that.  I appreciate it.
